# How to get active users of Dapp

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-debugging, dapp-design

Is it possible to have unique constraint on parameters of an event? I will have a number of users using my Dapp, and I have provided functionality to delete the users. So while reading from the transaction log, I will get a list of all the users created to date. I want only the users that are active on my Dapp.

Comment: Too general. Please show your code and ask for more specific guidance on it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the active set users you need to combine the transaction logs of

`All created users - All deleted users`

Or considering storing your users in [EnumerableSet](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/EnumerableSet.sol) and you can directly query the active users using smart contract calls, instead of events.

Comment: What if the same user with the same public address decides to create an account again? This method won't work then, right?

Comment: Also will using EnurmerableSet be cheap? As each user has its own struct.

Comment: It is as cheap as it gets. Also naturally you can check in your `createAccount` if the address already exists in the set.